# Como alterar un campo en oracle para guardar solo la hora

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo la siguiente tabla creada en oracle pero al crear la hora puse como tipo date y quiero cambiar a un tipo de dato que me guarde unicamente la hora en el campo VUE_HORA_SALIDA[image: Desc tabla]

Comment: Viendo las otras columnas de tu bd, no entiendo por qué quieres hacer eso. **Puedes tener 1 sola columna** del tipo [`TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006050) que te almacene la fecha y hora de salida del vuelo, **en vez de tener dos columnas** para ello. Ahorrarías espacio, ganarías en simplicidad, y tendrías menos riesgo de error en los datos. Si luego sólo quieres presentar la hora de vuelo aparte, existen funciones para extraer sólo la hora de un campo `TIMESTAMP`. ¿Si puedes enviar dos paquetes en un solo viaje, por qué pagar dos viajes?

Answer (score 1):

No existe un tipo de dato `hour` (hora), lo que podes hacer es definir la columna como `DATE` (almacena la fecha y la hora).

Cuando necesites la hora utilizas la función `HOUR()` que retorna la hora (en formato 24 horas) de una fecha válida.

```
SELECT HOUR(campo) FROM tabla;
```

Cuando necesites la fecha usas la función `TO_CHAR()` que retorna una cadena que contiene la fecha de acuerdo al formato específicado.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(campo, "DD-MM-YYYY") FROM tabla;
```

---

No es necesario tener un campo para almacenar la hora (`VUE_HORA_SALIDA`) y otro para la fecha (`VUE_FECHA_SALIDA`), sino que se pueden agrupar en un solo campo que se llame `VUE_SALIDA`. Lo mismo ocurre con `VUE_HORA_LLEGADA` y `VUE_FECHA_LLEGADA`.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Matias Olivera

Answer (score 0):

Hola Yo lo he solucionado con una caden de caractares de 5 `VARCHAR2(5)` pues la hora va en formato 24H `15:50` y vale para ordenar. 
En mi caso la validación de 0-24 y 0-59 lo hago en validador de la aplicación, pero supongo que si lo necesitas podrás hacer un disparador del `before insert`.

En mi migración de MySQL a Oracle lo he hecho así y de momento funciona.